# Prohibit WindowsMediaPlayer wmmpsMediaEnded event

Tags: c#, windows-media-player

I have **C# program** in which I use **WMPLib WindowsMediaPlayer**. When playing goes to an end, it goes to these states:
**wmppsMediaEnded --> wmppsTransitioning --> wmppsStopped**.

By going to this chain of states, WindowsMediaPlayer.controls.currentPosition sets to **0**;

So when player goes to an end, it stops playing and when I click play button, it starts playing from the start again.

I want player **not to go** into **wmppsMediaEnded** state and therefore **not to start** from beginning afterwards.
Is it possible?

I expected that **WindowsMediaPlayer** should have property, that prohibits to go to the **wmppsMediaEnded** state when playing ends, but it does not.

Comment: Is there a way to hook into the event chain with your custom event handlers? It is a common pattern to have a property like `Handled` or `Cancel` on an event that once set to `true` causes the event to not be processed any further.

Comment: Have you tried set the autoRewind setting to false? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmp/settings-setmode

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem. When player goes into **wmppsStopped** state, I set **WindowsMediaPlayer.controls.currentPosition = WmpInstance.currentMedia.duration;**

So when playing is finished, player position stays at the end, even though it goes into **stopped** state.